# Adding code snippets in TwinCAT3 TcXaeShell

Tags: twincat

How can I add code snippets in TcXaeShell enviroment for TwinCAT3 ?. Insert Code snippet command doesn't seem to work (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+X).

Comment: I don't know since I never usedthem. Maybe snippets do not work in XaeShell. You could use [hotstrings with AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s2) as an alternative.